# How to make enum value global and store it

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is probably a stupid question. Im developing an app that has themes, The user can choose a theme for the app

The themes are values stored in an enum

```
Enum Theme{light, dark, rose, violet,.... }
```

How to store the enum value for the app to remember on launch?

Comment: enums are by default required to be global.(in java at least)

Comment: SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tenfour04 already said - `SharedPreferences` are probably the correct store for something like this. Since your `Enum` is in fact an `int`, you can store it in there using `SharedPreferences.Editor`'s `putInt` method and afterwards receive it with `SharedPreferences`'s `getInt` method.

Also refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

This is written without IDE, but should be quite close.

```
// save it 
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("theme",(int)Theme.light);
bool success = editor.commit();

// get it again (2nd parameter is default value)
Theme selectedTheme = (Theme) sharedPreferences.getInt("theme", (int) Theme.dark)
```

EDIT:
An `Enum` is in java not an `int` - sorry, I thought of .NET.
Anyhow it is common practice to give an `Enum` an identifier (`int`) field. Using this field, you can serialize the selected value into the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: You can’t cast an enum to an int or vice versa. You might be thinking of getValue() and valueOf(). For future safety it would be best to give each enum value a unique ID field and use that instead of the ordinal value, which you might want to change later. Or just use int constants to begin with instead of an enum.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right. I was in my .NET world, sorry 
But it's also common practice to give an `Enum` an ID field and have `Enum Theme{light(1), dark(2),.... }`. Then parse it with `Theme.ValueOf()` and get the `int` with `getValue()`